# Calling functions on Entities from a Context in C#

Tags: c#, exception, entity, this

I have started with model-first and generated a database, and I've created partial classes for my entities so that I can perform operations on them.

My code in the context is getting fairly long, is redundant, and I want to be able to make calls, such as:

```
using (var db = new Context()) {
...
  db.MyEntity.ComputeDistance();
...
}

***ADDED***

public void ComputeDistance() {
    int distance = 0;
    MyEntity curr = this;
    while (curr.Parent != null) {
        distance++;
        curr = curr.parent;
    }
    this.Distance = distance;
}
```

And I can do this, except that whenever I try to navigate relational properties, I run into issues where lazy loading hasn't populated those variables, and a few other types of exceptions. I tried passing the DB to the functions, but then that got bothersome as sometimes I would want to use the function without using a db. I tried having the DB optional and it would create if it didn't already exist, but that still didn't work very well.

It seems like I'm just doing it wrong, and I haven't found any good examples of how to do it.

How do you guys handle these situations, or, how do you avoid them?

Please let me know if you need more detail, thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense, how would you compute the distance for an entire entity? Or is your code supposed to compute the distance between all records in the entity?

Comment: I've added the ComputeDistance function to elaborate further

Comment: can you also add your entity classes too?

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with this a bit more, and realized that I must have been storing an element from a previous instance of context. I've made sure that I don't use any elements that are from a context that has been disposed and everything seems to be working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the green tick. This removed the question from the StackOverflow queue of unresolved problems.